# Decimal with or without commas regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that allows decimals with or without commas.

I have -

```
^[0-9]*((,\d{3})?(,\d{3})?(,\d{3})?)*(\.[0-9]{1,10})?$
```

which seems to work in reg ex tester, but when I put it in my code it doesn't work.  If fails for 1,000.00, but not 1,000

I need it to accept 1, 1000, 1000.00, 1,000,000.123, 1223.456, 1,000,123.928 etc.

Comment: It works for me (both within Chroms JS console and in an online regex tester)

Comment: I am testing using (!$(textBox).val().match(RestrictionRegularExpressions.DECIMAL)) could that be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This regex seems to work (try it [here](http://regexpal.com/)), but it is slightly overcomplicated, while at the same time allowing inconsistent use of `,` (i.e 12345,789,000.123). This should solve that problem:

```
^\d{1,3}(?:(,?)\d{3}(?:\1\d{3})*)?(?:\.\d{1,10})?$
```

By using a backreference (`\1`) you can make sure that the `,` is either always used, or never.

Making digits in front of the `.` optional while still requiring them in front of a `,` is also possible, but slightly more complicated:

```
^(?:\d{1,3}(?:(,?)\d{3})?)?(?:\1\d{3})*(\.\d{1,10})?$
```

Comment: +1 for the backreference.  I had no idea you could use them like that!

Comment: Both of our solutions require a left-side of the decimal, I'm struggling to figure out a way to make that optional while not allowing things like `,000.123`

Comment: @RocketHazmat this is a good in-depth article about how they work: http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html but I actually prefer Cecchi's solution without the backreferences ^^

Comment: @Cecchi, use a lookbehind on the first comma. (I'll try it out and post it then)

Comment: @Cecchi, ah damn Javascript doesn't support lookbehinds, I totally forgot...  that makes things a bit more complicated (without duplicating most of the regex)

Comment: I just tried and it didn't work either. I test using                     if (!$(textBox).val().match("^\d{1,3}((?:\,\d{3})*|\d*)(\.\d{1,10})?$")) {
                        $(this).BaseControlPlugin(BaseControlMethodsEnum.AddUserNotification, { messageCode: 'G0060', notificationSource: NotificationSourceEnum.Inline });
                    }  and it failed no matter what I typed in.

Comment: then there is a problem with the code using the regex. @Cecchi, I have a solution, but it's a bit more complicated (I'll edit it now)

Comment: @Kev, does javascript support regexes as strings? try replacing your `"` around the regex with `/`

Comment: I have managed to get it to work  I use the following regex and it seems to work for me "^([1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2}(\,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]{0,10})?|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,}(\.[0-9]{0,10})?|0(\.[0-9]{0,10})?|(\.[0-9]{1,10})?)$"

Comment: I think this will not match stuff like 1223.456. Also you can remove all `{1}` and replace `{0,}` by `*`

Comment: It does match 1223.456 as well as 1,223.456

Comment: right, must have been a bug of regexpal. Anyway, I can't see why your original regex and mine and Cecchi's solutions wouldn't work for you :-/

Answer (score 3):

Here's another option for allowing well formatted numbers, with up to 10 decimals:

```
^\d{1,3}((?:\,\d{3})*|\d*)(\.\d{1,10})?$
```

If you wanted to allow `.123` without a integer (left-side of decimal), you could change the first `{1,3}` to `{0,3}`

Comment: I like this, it's actually a bit simpler than using a backreference.

Comment: Changing to {0,3}matches the empty string.  Is that intentional?

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?=[\d.])\d{0,3}(?:\d*|(?:,\d{3})*)(?:\.\d+)?$
```

This enforces consistent comma use, allows there to be no left hand side, and won't match the empty string, ensuring that the user has entered some sort of number into your form.

To make changes:

- Eliminate the opening Lookahead to allow empty strings
- Change `{0,3}` to `{1,3}` to require a LHS
- Change the final `+` to `{1,N}` to put a maximum precision.
- To set a max value, change (or add, to maintain not matching the empty string.) the opening lookahead to:
- `(?=(?:,?\d){0,N})` Where N is the maximum number of digits.
- To set a min value, change the opening lookahead to:
- `(?=(?:,?\d){M})` Where M is the minimum number of digits.
- Combine those for min/max.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

The following regular expression worked for me:

```
^[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*(\\.[0-9]+)?$
```

Which I tested using this page on W3Schools web-page: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_regexp_test. It accepts up to three digits followed by any sequence of a comma followed by 3 digits and end with an optional dot with at least on digit followed by any number of digits.

Hope that helps.