# how to capture numbers with multple digits and with or without commas?

Tags: regex

my regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/Hm5tIp/1/):
 
`.*Previous Balance.* (?<prev_balance>\d+)`

my data:

```
 Security
Code
Issuer/Security Date Reference Transaction Type Quantity Balance at
04 May 2018
SMARTSHARES ETF
APA ASIA PACIFIC - Price at 30/04/2018
$2.09242
Previous Balance 0
03/05/2018 0000000000 Investor Application 2,389 2,389
SMARTSHARES ETF
ASD AUS DIVIDEND - Price at 30/04/2018
$1.64378
Previous Balance 982
03/05/2018 0000000000 Regular Savings Plan 30 1,012
SMARTSHARES ETF
ASR AUS RESOURCES - Price at
30/04/2018 $4.58275
Previous Balance 0
03/05/2018 0000000000 Investor Application 1,091 1,091
SMARTSHARES ETF
DIV NZ DIVIDEND - Price at 30/04/2018
$1.08884
Previous Balance 1,440
03/05/2018 0000000000 Regular Savings Plan 46 1,486
SMARTSHARES ETF
EMF EMERGING MARKETS - Price at
30/04/2018 $1.30309
Previous Balance 0
03/05/2018 0000000000 Investor Application 7,674 7,674
SMARTSHARES ETF
EUF EUROPE - Price at 30/04/2018
$1.69312
Previous Balance 0
03/05/2018 0000000000 Investor Application 5,906 5,906
SMARTSHARES ETF
TWF TOTAL WORLD - Price at 30/04/2018
$2.11181
Previous Balance 0
03/05/2018 0000000000 Investor Application 2,367 2,367
SMARTSHARES ETF
USG US LARGE GROWTH - Price at
30/04/2018 $4.01132
Previous Balance 0
```

**How do I capture 982 or 1,440 or 0?**
The , in 1,440 seems to be my trouble. 
I was thinking using `(a|b) Matches the a or the b part of the subexpression.` e.g. `\d+|\d+,\d+` but I can't get it to work.maybe I need some anchoring?

note: working through this suggested [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071519/decimal-with-or-without-commas-regular-expression) which helps e.g. `\d{1,3}` 
`.*Previous Balance.* (?<prev_balance>[0-9]{1,3},[0-9]{1,3})` this just captures 1,440

Answer (score 0):

This here:

```
^Previous Balance\s+((?:\d|,)+)
```

matches 0, 982, 0, 1.440 etc. as `group(1)`. Demo: [link](https://regex101.com/r/qYZpo9/2).

The interesting part consists of:

- `\d` matches digits
- `|` is either-or
- `,` is a comma
- `(?: )` groups digits and commas together
- `(?:\d|,)+` means: repeated digits or commas

Alternatively, you can use a `[ ]` group with `\d` and `,`:

```
^Previous Balance\s*([\d,]+)
```

Another [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hm5tIp/2).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty solid regex pattern to match money amounts with optional comma:

```
^Previous Balance\s+\$?(([1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3})*)|\d+)?$
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/4u1cYq/1)

If you later find out the decimal point is also optional, use:

```
^Previous Balance\s+\$?(([1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3})*)|\d+)?(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

This matches amounts from 0 to 99,999 (and optionally 1-2 decimals).

Answer (score 0):

To match values like `982` or `1,440` or `0` and not `1,` you could match `Previous Balance` at the start of the line and capture the values that you want to match in a group.

[`^Previous Balance\s*([0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)?)$`](https://regex101.com/r/JPTxO5/1/)

**Details**

- `^` Assert the position at the start of the line
- `Previous Balance\s*` Match literally followed by zero or more whitespace characters `\s*`
- `(` Start capturing group (This will match and capture your value)

  - `[0-9]+` Match one or more ditits
  - `(?:,[0-9]+)?` Followed by an optional `?` non capturing group `(?:`  that matches a comma and one or more digits
- `)` Close capturing group
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line